# SSIS Path.Combine

Tags: ssis

I have a flatfile connection manager.  I am using a variable to define the source path and then using the expression to combine the path and filename.  Is there a function that will combine the paths, the the C# Path.Combine.  I want prevent errors where the value may or may not have the \ at the end of the path

Comment: Nothing native that I know of, but you could use a script task to call the C# Path.Combine function.

Comment: Thanks Tab. I am actually using that within the script task.  Are you saying to use the readwrite variables and set it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use `expression` to handle `\` check then follwing might help, haven't tested the expression though,

```
RIGHT( @[User::strFilePath] ,1) == "\\" ? @[User::strFilePath] + @[User::strFileName] :  @[User::strFilePath] + "\\" + @[User::strFileName]
```

It's using expression `ternary operator` to decide if `\` needs to append at the end of the filePath or not.

**Updated** to use `RIGHT` Function instead of LEFT and Reverse combo Function.

Little cleaner,

```
@[User::strFilePath] + (RIGHT(@[User::strFilePath] ,1) == "\\" ? "" : "\\") + @[User::strFileName]
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative option:  REPLACE(@[User::strFilePath] + "\" + @[User::strFileName], "\\", "\")